# Show message on specific custom option select Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, checkbox

I would like to **show a message when user select any specific custom option** in **Magento 1.9**.

I have two **checkbox** options: 'disposal' and 'installation'.

**Current Issue**

At the moment I can only show the message based on the headline title of the custom option, which is 'Delivery Options' (please see current code below).

**Desired Result**

If the custom option states 'disposal' I would like the message 'please disconnect device' to appear underneath. If the custom option states 'installation' I would like the message 'please connect device' to appear underneath.

**select.phtml code requiring edit/update**

```
    <?php if ($_option->getTitle() == 'Delivery Options')
    echo '<p>Please disconnect device for disposal.
    <br>Please connect device for installation.</p>' ?>
```

**select.phtml code in full**

```
<?php /* @var $this Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select */ ?>
<?php $_option = $this->getOption() ?>
<dt><label<?php if ($_option->getIsRequire()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($_option->getIsRequire()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo  $this->escapeHtml($_option->getTitle()) ?></label></dt>
<dd<?php if ($_option->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
    <div class="input-box">
        <?php echo $this->getValuesHtml() ?>
        <?php if ($_option->getTitle() == 'Delivery Options')
        echo '<p>Please ensure device is disconnected and empty prior to disposal collection.<br>Please ensure you have the correct fittings in place for installation (i.e. plumbing, power points etc.)</p>' ?>
        <?php echo $_option->getLabel() ?>
        <?php if ($_option->getIsRequire()): ?>
            <?php if ($_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO || $_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_CHECKBOX): ?>
                <span id="options-<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>-container"></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif;?>
    </div>
</dd>
```

Can anyone please suggest an update to my `select.phtml` file below, to get this working as desired? I presume it will be a jquery on click event.

Comment: So you want to display a custom message based on the item selection from a select in the product page from frontend ?

Comment: Hi Chester, that's correct. Or alternatively, if that can't be done, put a message underneath a specific 'custom option' option. For example, if a custom option is 'dispose' the message 'this is a dispose option'. My current code shows the messages regardless.

Comment: Can you update your post with the generated html code ? you can get it from firebug . thnx!

Comment: Hi Chester, is there a specific part of the output you require? As there seems to be lots of html generated by this file[s], including script.